# Modifying the keys of a JSON object

Tags: java, android, json

I am facing a rather nasty problem and couldn't find a good solution on the internet yet. I have an Android app that pulls down a large JSON object containing some information about the user. The format is as follows:

```
{
  "dateOfBirth": {
    "day": 25,
    "month": 3
  },
  "educations": {
    "_total": 1,
    "values": [{
      "activities": "Music Society, Rugby college team",
      "degree": "BA Computer Science",
      "endDate": {"year": 2015},
      "fieldOfStudy": "Computer Science",
      "id": 298659638,
      "notes": "The courses I enjoyed most are: Object-Oriented Programming, Data Structures and Algorithms, Compilers, Databases, Computer Networks and Computer Security.",
      "schoolName": "University of Oxford",
      "startDate": {"year": 2012}
    }]
  },
  "firstName": "Roland",
  "id": "-1QlZwe5fx",
  "languages": {
    "_total": 2,
    "values": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "language": {"name": "English"}
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "language": {"name": "Romanian"}
      }
    ]
  },
  "lastName": "Batovski",
  "location": {"country": {"code": "gb"}}
...
}
```

The server that I have to send this data to has a specific format of the JSON that it expects, i.e it expects data to come in this format:

```
{
​
    "userid": "Yohv74kuNm",
​
    "profile": [],
​
    "goalData": [
​
        "Founders",
​
        "Travel"
​
    ],
​
    "event": "1",
​
    "pin": "",
​
    "_id": "c9lZlvo9SEcIwDBR",
​
    "person": {
​
        "id": {
​
            "text": "Yohv74kuNm"
​
        },
​
        "languages": {
​
            "total": "2",
​
            "language": [
​
                {
​
                    "id": {
​
                        "text": "57739336"
​
                    },
​
                    "language": {
​
                        "name": {
​
                            "text": "English"
​
                        }
​
                    }
​
                }
​
            ]
​
        },
​
        "skills": {
​
            "total": "15",
​
            "skill": [
​
                {
​
                    "id": {
​
                        "text": "11"
​
                    },
​
                    "skill": {
​
                        "name": {
​
                            "text": "Start-ups"
​
                        }
​
                    }
​
                },
​
                {
​
                    "id": {
​
                        "text": "13"
​
                    },
​
                    "skill": {
​
                        "name": {
​
                            "text": "Entrepreneurship"
​
                        }
​
                    }
​
                },
... }
```

Obviously these objects are quite different but essentially they hold the same data. I'm looking for a method to easily map one to the other. i.e take the data from the one that I receive, and create a new JSON object that I fill in. Do keep in mind that these objects are rather large and have a lot of nested values. I tried using JavaEE's JsonObjectBuilder but creating an object that size seems like a lot of manual work (I gave a quick try below).

```
JsonObject jsonString = factory.createObjectBuilder()
        // add the fields here
        .add("id", factory.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("text", this.jsonObject.get("id").getAsString())
            .build())
        .add("languages", factory.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("total", this.jsonObject.get("languages").getAsJsonObject().get("_total").getAsString())
                .build())
        .build()
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

- Use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to serialize / deserialize JSON / POJOs.
- Have one class structure for JSON structure 1.
- Have another class structure for JSON structure 2.
- Keep them both in different packages, just for clarity.
- Use [this tool](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to automatically create the class structures.
- Write a converter to convert the java objects deserialized from json 1 to json 2- compatible java objects.

Another possibility would be to have your java objects reflect one of the two json structures and use a [custom serializer](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization) to work with the other json structure.

Comment: This is sort of what I was trying to do. The problem I am facing is writing the converter you are talking about. Is that not going to be very complex given the complex structure of the JSON object?

Comment: @RolandBatovski Yes it might become quite complex depending on how much the two json formats do differ in their structure. But at least you'd be working with (type safe) java objects instead of building the json string yourself which would be way more tedious and error-prone. 
Somebody else might have a better suggestion though.

Comment: I understand :) Thanks a lot for this! Will look into it